# Please add a warning when deleting a saved list

Tags: feature-request, saves

Please add a warning somewhere in this "Edit list" modal to inform the user that all their saved items in the list will be unsaved when deleting the list (or revert back to "All saves" or "For later", which is currently not the case)

Currently there is no confirmation or warning about this.

[image]

Comment: Would it be better to just have them revert back to 'All saves' instead?